# R: Matrix and Vectors

Tags: r, csv, matrix, vector

I was given an amount of data to put into a matrix and vector. It's a csv file with 11 columns and 10 rows. I need to have the matrix A be the first 10x10, and the vector b be the last column. I also need to solve Ax = b. I'm having a bit of trouble with what I should do. I'm an extremely new programmer, but have a background in C and SQL. I'd appreciate any criticism on how I can improve my coding.

```
read.csv("p5.csv") //dealing with the csv file
data = read.csv("p5.csv")

x = read.csv("p5.csv", header = FALSE)
A = matrix(x, nrow = 10, ncol = 10) //my poor attempt to set the required 
dimensions
b = matrix(x, nrow = 10, ncol = 1) //poor attempt to set up vector
```

From here I know I need to use the **vector inverse** in order to solve the Ax = b. But I'm unsure if I'm on the right track here.

Comment: You need to _subset_ x with something like `A = x[1:10, ];  b = x[11,]`   Then use `solve` to solve the equation.   Look at the help page  `?solve`

Comment: Your description of rows and columns seems inconsistent. You say that the data has 11 *rows* but only 10 columns and then turn around and say you want `b` to be the 11th `column` of the data. Which is it?

Comment: If you set `header = FALSE`, then maybe it's better to use the more general purpose `read.table`. If the values are separated by commas you would set `sep = ','`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some basic subsetting. Look into some introductory R courses. You can learn R in R using swirl (http://swirlstats.com/), for example.

```
data <- read.csv("p5.csv")
A <- data[,1:10]
b <- data[,11]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. We hadn't learned how to do that. Thanks for the link!